# UnicodeEncodeError at /notifications/ajax/ 'ascii' codec can't encode character: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I recently switched some word(string) to non-english language. And now I get this error in console. I'm using python, django. and this is happening from ajax. I believe in python file I just need to add "    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
" at the top. I did same thing for where my ajax is, but it does nothing.
Here;s the full error

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /notifications/ajax/
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ubbbb' in position 98: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback:
File "/home/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/notifications/views.py" in get_notifications_ajax
  47.           notes.append(str(note.get_link))

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /notifications/ajax/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ubbbb' in position 98: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here;s the function for ajax

```
@login_required
def get_notifications_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        notifications = Notification.objects.all_for_user(MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)).recent()
        count = notifications.count()
        notes = []
        for note in notifications:
            notes.append(str(note.get_link))
        data = {
            "notifications": notes,
            "count": count,
        }
        print data
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        print json_data
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

the error is occuring from here;

```
notes.append(str(note.get_link))
```

Here's my ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".notification-toggle").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'get_notifications_ajax' %}",
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
          },
         success: function(data){
            $("#notification_dropdown").html(' <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">view</li>');
            var count = data.count
            console.log(count)
            if (count == 0) {
              var url = '{% url "notifications_all" %}'
              $("#notification_dropdown").append("<li><a href='" + url+ "'>view all</a></li>")
            } else {
              $(data.notifications).each(function(){
                var link = this;
                $("#notification_dropdown").append("<li>" + link + "</li>")
              })
            }
            console.log(data.notifications);
          },
          error: function(rs, e) {
            console.log(rs);
            console.log(e);
          }
        })
      })
    })
    </script>
```

What I switched is "verb" on this one:
    notify.send(MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    action=new_comment,
                    target=parent_comment, 
                    recipient=parent_comment.user, 
                    affected_users=affected_users,
                    verb='replied')

I translated 'replied' to korean and I got the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str` on the Korean character is going to fail in python 2 - you should be using `.encode()` for this. So changing `str(note.get_link)` to `note.get_link.encode('utf-8')` should get things working.

[Check out the unicode how to in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type)

```
>>> x = u'\ubbbb'
>>> x
u'\ubbbb'
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> str(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ubbbb' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> x.encode('utf-8')
'\xeb\xae\xbb'
```

Comment: it should be like str(note.get_link.encode('utf-8')) right?

Comment: wait so I should remove str and just (note.get_link.encode('utf-8'))?

Comment: I would remove str unless you need it.`str(x.encode('utf-8'))` is still just `'\xeb\xae\xbb'`

Comment: hmm ok, I should probably read the docu. it worked with str(note.get_lin.encode... but i'll remove str

Comment: hello, I get the same error for   context = {
   "sender": self.sender_object,
   "verb": self.verb,
   "action": self.action_object,
   "target": self.target_object,
   "verify_read": reverse("notifications_read", kwargs={"id": self.id}),
   "target_url": target_url,
  }
  if self.target_object:
   return "<a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s</a>" %context

Comment: Would help if you could post the code, what you expected to see and the error you're seeing instead. there's not enough context otherwise

Comment: here, I posted the question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643855/the-moment-i-put-a-string-thats-non-english-word-whole-thing-disappears/36646153#36646153